# How to check if values in dictionaries are the same? Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary made by:

```
d={'name':(values), (values), (values), 'name2':(values),(values), ...ecc}
```

so values are tuples.
I want to check if some tuples associated to a value are the same.

Comment: Your parentheses don't match up.

Comment: Hint: the `==` operator checks for equality...

Comment: @n9code please do not edit code to add/remove things like parentheses. Instead, leave a comment for the OP questioning their intent.

Comment: Please add an **minimal** example with *actual* values that contain *matching* and *non-matching* tuples.  Please include the desired result.  If you have made an attempt, please post that as well.

Answer (score -3):

How you define "the same"? Does `(1, 2)` should be "the same" as `(2, 1)`?

If `(1, 2)` isn't "the same" as `(2, 1)` you can simply iterate over the values and check if they are equal with the `==` operator.

If `(1, 2)` is "the same" as `(2, 1)` you can sort them (or simply turn them into a `set`) and then do the same as above.

**EDIT:** Since you clarified that you want the first behavior, you can create a new dictionary with dictionary comprehension (assuming you are using Python 2.7 or above) and turning each list of tuples to a set of tuples:

```
d = {'a': [(1,1), (1,1), (1,2)], 'b': [(3,3), (2,5), (3,3)]}

new_d = { k:list(set(v)) for k,v in d.iteritems() }

>> {'a': [(1, 2), (1, 1)], 'b': [(2, 5), (3, 3)]}
```

Comment: `(1,2)` does not equal `(2,1)`.

Comment: `a = (1, 2)
b = (2, 1)
set(a) == set(b)` returns `True`. It's up to the OP to decide what "the same" means.

Comment: no , differen values in tuple are always in the same order!

Comment: OP wants to *check* which implies a boolean outcome.  This removes duplicates.